# Could you please help and explain to me how to correct the seemingly incorrect passive voice sentence pattern?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage, passive-voice, sequence-of-tenses, is-it-a-rule

Could you please help and explain to me how to correct the seemingly incorrect passive voice sentence pattern?

- *I would prefer it if we could be sat next to a window.*

Comment: What do you think is seemingly incorrect here?

Comment: Does that mean the sentence, "I would prefer it if we could be sat there?" is correct? The Grammarly app gave a message that, accordingly, it is a passive voice misuse. But, honestly, I have a feeling that it is correct. I am not jut really sure about it and can't even explain the tense.

Comment: Ushers and hosts sit you. They sit you in your favorite seat or sit you at the worst table. You are sat by them. That is the passive voice, and it is correct — if you want to use the passive voice. https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/sit

Answer (score 1):

The statement is ungrammatical, and needs 'seated' if an active, punctive usage is required. 'Seat [someone etc]' is transitive; 'sit' is usually intransitive (and therefore resists/disallows passivisation). But then '*I would prefer it if we could sit next to a window*' would be far more idiomatic.

However, there is a possibility that the stative, durative sense

- '*I would prefer it if we could be sitting next to a window* [when the rest of the party arrives, say].' is the intended sense.  'The following is an extract from [an article by Patricia T. O’Conner and Stewart Kellerman in Grammarphobia](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2017/12/sat-stood.html):

> *We were sat … or were we?  December 1, 2017*
>
> Q: Do all British people say “sat” instead of “sitting,” as in this
> example from a Brit’s blog: “We were sat around the coffee table”?
>
> A: No, not all British people would say something like “We were sat
> around the coffee table.” That usage isn’t considered standard English
> in either the UK or the US.
>
> However, quite a few people in the UK do indeed use “sat” that way,
> and the usage shows up once in a while in the US too.
>
> In an Oct. 3, 2012, post on the Oxford Dictionaries blog, the
> lexicographer Catherine Soanes notes the increasing nonstandard use of
> the past participles “sat” and “stood” for the present participles
> “sitting” and “standing” in British English.
>
> She reports hearing several instances of the usage on the BBC,
> including “She’s sat at the table eating breakfast” and “we were stood
> at the bar waiting to be served.”
>
> Soames, editor or co-editor of several Oxford dictionaries, says the
> use of “sat” and “stood” for “sitting” and “standing” in continuous,
> or progressive, tenses is “regarded as non-standard by usage guides.”

So in this case also, the choice of 'could be sat' is non-standard.

Comment: Is this like "seated", as in "Please be seated" and "If you would please be seated, we could get started" and "He had been seated by the door, where he was no longer sitting"?

Comment: Those are tricky, which is why I avoided them. [CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/seated) has: << **seated** [adjective]
 B2 _sitting_:
• The woman seated opposite him kept staring at him. / • You are requested to remain seated during take-off. / • [formal] Ladies and gentlemen, please be seated (= please sit down). >> But it's interesting that 'stood' doesn't work here. I'll avoid 'lain'/'laid'. Your third example shows a stative usage, which better fits with the adjective analysis. But your first two are obviously (exhortations to the) dynamic. More verby. The ...

Comment: antonym 'Please be upstanding' complicates rather than helps. I think I'll stick with saying they're idioms.